# Nginx is logging 301 entries in the wrong access file

Tags: nginx, logging, log-files

I have a question about how 301 entries are logged. A bit of background:

I created a new Ubuntu/Nginx server and added a site. By default, NGINX logs to `/var/log/nginx/access.log`

I edited one site conf log to its own file::

```
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/www.foo.com-error.log error;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/www.foo.com-access.log;
```

The site logs successfully, except that 301 entries are still being logged in the default access log.

For example:

This record:

```
06/Dec/2019:16:54:28 +0000 - 111.111.111.111 - www.foo.com - GET / HTTP/1.1 - 301 - 169 - - - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362 - 111.111.111.111
```

Is being logged to `/var/log/nginx/access.log` instead of `/var/log/nginx/www.foo.com-access.log`

I'd like to do two things, but I don't know how:

- Make sure that anything related to foo.com is being logged to the foo.com-access file including 301 entries.
- Add a field to the `log_format` that shows where the request is redirecting to (not just the referrer from) in the log.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you got other server blocks? Maybe there is defined default behavior for access_log.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked and there is another block before that looks like this:
```server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name .foo.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}```

Comment: I'm inferring that each block needs to have its own access log rule? Is there a way to define an access log to every server block?

Comment: @Daniel - Your comment helped solve my problem. Thank you!